# Listview button click listener is not working

Tags: java, android, button, adapter, onclicklistener

I'm using an `adapter` class to set values for my items. For each item there is a `+` and a `-` button. I have a `foodActivity` java class, `activity_food` layout for the java class and a `list_view_layout` for the lists. I have initialized the `+` and `-` buttons inside my activity class. When the `activity_food` starts, the app crashes.

[image: This is my item list image]

**plus, minus and edittext in list_view_layout -**

```js
<Button
    android:id="@+id/minus"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/foodname"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/foodpic"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/quantity"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/foodname"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/minus"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/plus"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/quantity"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/quantity"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

**activity_food layout -**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.res.easyorder.foodActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="#ffff"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My adapter class -**

```js
package com.res.easyorder;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<item> {

    int q_ty = 0;
    ArrayList<item> foodlist = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<item> objects){

        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        foodlist = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){

        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, null);

        ImageView foodpic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.foodpic);
        TextView foodname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.foodname);
        TextView foodprice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.foodprice);
        Button plus = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        final EditText quantity = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        Button minus = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.minus);

        plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                item item = getItem(position);
                q_ty = Integer.parseInt(item.getQuantity());
                q_ty = q_ty + 1;
                quantity.setText("" +q_ty);
            }
        });


        foodname.setText(foodlist.get(position).getFoodName());
        foodpic.setImageResource(foodlist.get(position).getFoodImage());
        foodprice.setText("BDT: " +foodlist.get(position).getFoodPrice());
        quantity.setText(foodlist.get(position).getQuantity());

        return v;
    }
}
```

**foodActivity java code. Plus minus onclicklistener is being commented -**

```js
package com.res.easyorder;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class foodActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String type = null;
    int quantity = 0;

    private Button plus, minus;
    private EditText q_ty;

    ListView simplelist;
    ArrayList<item> foodlist = new ArrayList<>();
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        simplelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
        q_ty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantity);

        type = getIntent().getExtras().getString("type");

        if(type.equals("breakfast"))
        {
            foodlist.add(new item("Rooti",R.drawable.ruti,5));
            foodlist.add(new item("Parata",R.drawable.porata,8));
            foodlist.add(new item("Tandoor",R.drawable.tandoor,15));
            foodlist.add(new item("Vegetable",R.drawable.sodji,10));
            foodlist.add(new item("Daal",R.drawable.dal,10));
            foodlist.add(new item("Omelet",R.drawable.dimvaji,15));
            foodlist.add(new item("Singara",R.drawable.singara,8));
            foodlist.add(new item("Samosa",R.drawable.samosa,10));
            foodlist.add(new item("Puri",R.drawable.puri,5));

        }
        

        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.list_view_layout,foodlist);
        simplelist.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        /*plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //quantity = quantity + 1;
                //q_ty.setText(""+quantity);
            }
        });

        minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (quantity==0)
                {
                    //q_ty.setText(""+quantity);
                }

                else if (quantity>0)
                {
                    quantity = quantity - 1;
                    //q_ty.setText(""+quantity);
                }
            }
        });*/
    }

   
}
```

Comment: put your adapter code here

Comment: you have added button in other layout file and accessing in different file definitely it will crash

Comment: make custom adapter and bind into listview and using adapter handle minus and plus operation.

Comment: add the adapter here for review and the crash logs also

Comment: okay. I have put my adapter class. @LokeshDesai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing this problem because you have plus minus button on Listview item row xml file and you are finding plus minus button in activity. You have to put your click listener in your adapter class

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.quantity= (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        holder.plus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        holder.minus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Item item = getItem(position);

    holder.quantity.setText(item.getQuantity());

    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        Item item = getItem(position); 
        q_ty = Integer.parseInt(item.getQuantity()); 
        q_ty = q_ty + 1; 
        quantity.setText("" +q_ty);
        item.setQuantity(q_ty);
        }
    });



    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try it. I will let you know.

Comment: what is ViewHolder? @FazalHussain

Comment: ViewHolder is only a class which "holds" the reference to the objects plus, minus and quantity.

Comment: I have put my adapter class in the post. I have written the onclicklistener inside my adapter class. But there is a problem. The value is increasing only one time. It does not increase second time after increasing first time. Please check my adapter class and let me know the issue. @FazalHussain

Comment: Please, check your implementation. You update the textview but not the item which hold the quantity...

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the OnClicklistener in your "MyAdapter.getView(..)" method, because in this method the items are created. Currently in your foodActivity.onCreate() methode the objects plus, minus and q_ty are null.

Comment: let me try. I will let you know.